# NumberFormatException while parsing color

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse color from `String` to `int`. It works most of the time but there are some specific cases that throws `NumerFormatException`.

Example of colors that couldn't be parsed:

- 003976
- 631b4b

**Code that I use to parse color:**

```
  try {
      dialogView.findViewById(R.id.test_view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + shop.getBackgroundColor()));
  } catch (Exception e) { 
      Log.e("test", e.getMessage());
  }
```

**Exception I get:**

[image]

**From debugger:**

[image]

It's weird because debugger shows that count of `String` is equal 8. In different cases it shows count equals 7 and parsing works. Any ideas what's wrong here and how to solve it?

## EDIT

I found that returned `String` from `getBackgroundColor()` method has additional invisible character at the beginning like `'\uFEFF' 65279`. I removed it and now it works. Thanks

Comment: look at each individual character in the debugger execution for the getBackgroundColor thing under `value`... my suspicion is that there's some invisible characters at the end of the string

Comment: There is an extra " on your shop.getBackgroundColor() string.

Answer (score 0):

What type is your getBackgroundColor() method in shop class? It seems that it is Long, and 631b4b is not long decimal, it's hex. You can make it to return String.

Comment: getBackgroundColor() method returns String

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`shop.getBackgroundColor()` may return with white spaces. Just remove it using `trim()`. like this,.

`shop.getBackgroundColor().trim()`

```
 try {
      dialogView.findViewById(R.id.test_view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + shop.getBackgroundColor().trim()));
  } catch (Exception e) { 
     Log.e("test", e.getMessage());
  }
```